# Overwrite background-color (css)

Tags: css

I have an input that has two classes with background-color that I need to overwrite. I'm trying to do this: put that input in a external container, and (with javascript) I will change the class of that container to the desire one.

The input has two classes as I said, and those classes are the one which I need to change: irs-line and irs-bar. Those two classes has their own background-color's. I need them on red and yellow. I will trigger the change of classes via javascript with the value of some radio buttons. (that's another story)

My question is, in some forum, a guy give me this hint:

```
.container.color-yellow .irs-line {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.container.color-red .irs-line {
    background-color: red;
}
```

But I'm not sure how it works or how I should use those classes in the input. Any help? (I would ask to that guy what were trying he to do but I can't)

UPDATE:

This is my code where I call the input:

```
<div className="uk-width-1-4">
    <input type="text" name="timewmsslider" ref="timewmsslider" />
</div>
```

It's Reacjs, so with ref="timewmsslider" is how the input is defined with their default irs-bar and irs-line classes.

That input is being generated with the default irc-line and irc-bar css classes. So, how should I call if I have this classes in the css (for both colors red and yellow)?

```
.irs-line-yellow {
    height: 16px;
    top: 24px;
    border-radius:8px;
    border: #EEEEEE 1px solid;
    background: #e9d759; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #e9d759 0%, #e9d759 70%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #e9d759 0%,#e9d759 70%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #e9d759 0%,#e9e459 70%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e9d759', endColorstr='#e9d759',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 0!important;
}

.irs-bar-yellow {
    height: 16px;
    top: 24px;
    margin-left: -7px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    background: #e9d759; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #e9d759 0%, #e9d759 70%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #e9d759 0%,#e9d759 70%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #e9d759 0%,#e9d759 70%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e9d759', endColorstr='#e9d759',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-radius:8px;
    border: #EEEEEE 1px solid;
}

.irs-bar-red {
    height: 16px;
    top: 24px;
    margin-left: -7px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    background: #e95959; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #e95959 0%, #e95959 70%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #e95959 0%,#e95959 70%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #e95959 0%,#e95959 70%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e95959', endColorstr='#e95959',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-radius:8px;
    border: #EEEEEE 1px solid;
}
.irs-line-red {
    height: 16px;
    top: 24px;
    border-radius:8px;
    border: #EEEEEE 1px solid;
    background: #e95959; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #e95959 0%, #e95959 70%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #e95959 0%,#e95959 70%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #e95959 0%,#e95959 70%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e95959', endColorstr='#e95959',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 0!important;
}
```

I have to change the input classes with those ones depending on externala actions (some radio buttons will change the color of the bar and line via javascript)

Default case: http://jsfiddle.net/h307fdau/
Red case: http://jsfiddle.net/mxt78oa5/

Comment: You simply change "color-red" for "color-yellow" and viceversa.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Can you post the actual markup of what you've tried as oppose to hypothetical markup?...

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the question, I will add exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your latest HTML & CSS fiddle edits, I'd suggest the following jQuery:

1.Keep these CSS classes to best isolate the needed `background-color` property as you did in the shared fiddle in comments:

```
.red {background-color: red;}
.yellow {background-color: yellow;}
```

2.This jQuery will add or remove color classes according to radio `input` selection & remove any colors if they match "actual" string value on slider:

```
$range.on("change", function() {
    //store slider & radio inputs values
    var value = $(".js-range-slider").prop("value");
    var radioColor = $(".extra-controls input[type=radio]:checked").val();
    //if value matches actual remove colors
    if (value == 'actual') {
        $(".irs-line").removeClass(radioColor);
        $(".irs-bar").removeClass(radioColor);
        //prevent bottom line from coloring on slider actual date
        $("#escenario-moderado").on("change", function() {
            $(".irs-line").removeClass("yellow");
            $(".irs-bar").removeClass("yellow");
        });
        $("#escenario-severo").on("change", function() {
            $(".irs-line").removeClass("red");
            $(".irs-bar").removeClass("red");
        });
    }
    //else add the default radio input selected color
    else {
        $(".irs-line").addClass(radioColor);
        $(".irs-bar").addClass(radioColor);
        //add manually selected radio color
        $("#escenario-moderado").on("change", function() {
            $(".irs-bar").addClass("yellow");
            $(".irs-line").addClass("yellow");
            $(".irs-line").removeClass("red");
            $(".irs-bar").removeClass("red");
        });
        $("#escenario-severo").on("change", function() {
            $(".irs-line").addClass("red");
            $(".irs-bar").addClass("red");
            $(".irs-bar").removeClass("yellow");
            $(".irs-line").removeClass("yellow");
        });
    }
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Syden/cpnv56rx/)

Comment: The default value shouldn't be colored. In the "actual" year the bar has to be grey (no colored added). Look, I was doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/pqmtbpmz/

Comment: ahh nicer. I need to start without colors as I said, and I don't have to change them when the year is "actual", but if I change the year, the color has to take the checked radio button,

Comment: Sí, va bien, sólo que no debe cambiar cuando el año es "actual", sólo cambia de color (al que tiene el radio button) cuando es otro año.

Comment: Sí, sólo que igual se puede cambiar cuando está en ese año, en mi jsfiddle estaba tratando de que eso no ocurriera, me funciona pero cuando cambio de año y vuelvo al actual, ahí se sigue cambiando el color.

Comment: Tu solución es mucho mejor en todo caso, sólo estoy ahora tratando de añadir lo que te comenté, que sólo se pueda cambiar cuando no es año actual, y que cuando se mueva sin hacer clic en los radio buttons que tome el valor del que estaba ya seleccionado. Va re bien

Comment: Gracias, probaré ahora. Todo perfect, sólo que antes podía cambiar de color con los click en los radio buttons estando en años distintos al actual, ahora sólo se cambian cuando hay onchange del radio button (lo cual también es necesario para el caso de salir del "actual"), fíjate acá: http://jsfiddle.net/pqmtbpmz/ ahí puedo cambiar de color estando en otro año distinto al actual.

Comment: Traté de meter el click dentro del else pero no tiene que cambiar cuando la fecha sea actual, y me cambia igual. http://jsfiddle.net/py1up40v/

Comment: Todo bien maestro, gracias. El tema de que no cambie de color cuando esté en actual lo haré de otra forma nomás, desactivaré el input del rangeslider cuando el año sea actual, ya que no se debe cambiar de color cuando es actual. Muchas gracias, respuesta correcta entonces.

Comment: Listo, todo bien, hice algunos cambios menores, agregué un par de if, estoy usando esto dentro de un código de Reactjs, pero la idea principal ya está, muchas gracias nuevamente. Dejo el código por siacaso: http://pastebin.com/mU6uSEYC